# wcf restful service method input parameter: string vs stream

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, service

Can anybody explain me?
What is the difference between wcf methods with string and stream input parameters?

void method1(Stream input)
and
void method2(string input)

When one should use stream input parameter?
What are benefits and disadvantages and limits for each of these approaches?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use a `Stream` parameter if you want to receive all the bytes from the incoming HTTP request body in your operation. That's the "raw" mode which I mentioned at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx, and you can use it to receive arbitrary data.

You'd use a `string` parameter if you want to receive a well-formatted string in any of the supported formats. Out of the box, that means either JSON (the string value surrounded by `"`) or XML (depending on the body style of the operation, either a XML element node called `<string>` whose text is the value passed to the operation, or an element with the name of the operation, with a child element named by the parameter, whose child text node is the value passed to the operation.